# How to check if a variable is either a python list, numpy array or pandas series

Tags: python, arrays, list, pandas, numpy

I have a function that takes in a variable that would work if it is any of the following three types

```
 1. pandas Series
 2. numpy array (ndarray)
 3. python list
```

Any other type should be rejected. What is the most efficient way to check this?

Comment: What about a `tuple`?  I ask because you might be over-restricting your input.

Comment: So what do you suggest to check if the input is a list-like object, including np.ndarray and pd.Series? I was looking for something more elegant than the currently accepted answer anyway.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You can do it using `isinstance`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
def f(l):
    if isinstance(l,(list,pd.core.series.Series,np.ndarray)):
        print(5)
    else:
        raise Exception('wrong type')
```

Then `f([1,2,3])` prints 5 while `f(3.34)` raises an error.

Comment: What's the difference between `pd.core.series.Series` and `pd.Series`?

Comment: @Zhang18, you could use pd.Series as well. I used pd.core.series.Series just because type(pd.Series([1,2,3])) gives pd.core.series.Series. Yet, both of them work, as pd.Series==pd.core.series.Series is True

Comment: Likely, `Series` is actually defined in the `pd.core.series` module, but then the `Series` class is imported from there into the top-level `__init__.py` for convenience.

Answer (score 22):

Python type() should do the job here

```
l = [1,2]
s= pd.Series(l)
arr = np.array(l)
```

When you print

```
type(l)
list

type(s)
pandas.core.series.Series

type(arr)
numpy.ndarray
```

Answer (score 12):

The other answers are good but I sort of prefer this way:

```
if np.ndim(l)!=0:
    # this is something like a series, list, ndarray, etc.
```

It is nice because it provides more duck-typing flexibility compared to:

```
if isinstance(l, (pd.Series, list, np.ndarray)):
    # this is ONLY a pd.Series, list, or ndarray
```

...but it is better than this, which will allow a string or an iterator though-- both of which are often not wanted:

```
if isinstance(l, typing.Iterable):
    # this any iterable
```

...or this, which excludes a string but (weirdly) does not exclude an iterator:

```
if not np.isscalar(l):
    # this is something like a series, list, ndarray, etc.
```

However, if you truly only want a `list`, `ndarray`, or `Series`, the other answers are preferable.

Answer (score 4):

This all really depends on what you are trying to achieve (will you allow a tuple, how about a `range` object?), but to be a bit less restrictive but still disallow strings (which I am guessing is what you are really trying to achieve) you can use the following code.

```
import collections
import pandas
import numpy

def myfunc(x):
    if not isinstance(x, collections.abc.Iterable) or isinstance(x, (str, bytes)):
        raise ValueError('A non-string iterable is required')
    return 'Yay!'

myfunc([9, 7])
myfunc((9, 7))
myfunc(numpy.arange(9))
myfunc(range(9))
myfunc(pandas.Series([9, 7]))
myfunc('Boo')  # THIS WILL RAISE A ValueError!!!!!
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use isinstance like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#Simple List
simple_list = [1,2]  

#numpy array
np_array = np.array(simple_list) 

#Pandas series
pandas_series = pd.Series(simple_list)  


if isinstance(simple_list, list):
    print("This is a list: ", simple_list)

if isinstance(np_array, np.ndarray):
    print("This is a numpy array: ", np_array)

if isinstance(pandas_series, pd.core.series.Series):
    print("This is pandas series: ", pandas_series)
```

Answer (score 1):

While the accepted answer uses the built-in [`isinstance`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance), which itself should the preferred way when the accepted dtypes is/are known.

In my opinion, it is much more flexible and robust to use checks from `pandas.api.types` which cover a broader dtype checking. For example, [`pd.api.types.is_list_like`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.api.types.is_list_like.html) checks for objects that are considered list-like are for example Python lists, tuples, sets, NumPy arrays, and Pandas Series.

Notice here that we can test for nested as well as flat list like objects also,

```
import pandas as pd

pd.api.types.is_list_like([1,2,3]), pd.api.types.is_list_like(np.array([[1], [2], [3]]))
```

> (True, True)

While below gives,

```
pd.api.types.is_list_like("This is a string not a list like object")
```

> False

This is particularly useful when more wider checks are required, for example using [`pandas.api.types.is_re_compilable`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.api.types.is_bool_dtype.html) to check if input string can be compiled into valid regex pattern and using [`pandas.api.types.is_datetime64_ns_dtype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.api.types.is_bool_dtype.html) to check if input is of datetime64[ns] dtype.